# Is it possible to remove a variable from an expression?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the Expression:

$$\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6} + \dfrac{6N}{6}− \dfrac{3N(N+1)}{6}$$

Is it possible to remove N from the third expression to give -3 / 6, giving a final expression of:

$$\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1-3)+6N}{6}$$

If so, what is this called. And how can I learn more about when to do it.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please confirm that the recently edited version of the question is the same as what you have in front of you?

Comment: yes this is great, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of the distributive property. And yes you can do this with it. One way to think of it is to say $\frac{N(N+1)}{6}$ is a thing. I have 2N+1 or them over here, and -3 of them over here. They are being added(or subtracted) together, so I can put them together.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove the $N(N-1)$ as $\frac {-3N(N-1)}6 \neq \frac {-3}6$.  What you are doing is use the distributive property and the fact that the first term has factors of $N(N-1)$ as well, so what you are doing is fine.